# Leave only fields with string values

Tags: json, string, jq, key-value

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
  "1": "a-secret",
  "A": "b-secret",
  "2": {
    "3": "ab-secret",
    "4": {
      "5": "adc-secret"
    },
    "6": {
      "7": "abdc-secret"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a command (preferable one liner) to return key pairs that only have string values. So for the above it would return:

```
{
  "1": "a-secret",
  "A": "b-secret"
}
```

I have found `.[]|strings` that returns only the string values but I need both the key and value and that's where I'm stumped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`map_values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)).

```sh
$ jq 'map_values(strings)' file
{
  "1": "a-secret",
  "A": "b-secret"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution, especially on versions prior to `jq-1.6` you could use `with_entries` to filter on values whose type is `string`

```
with_entries(select(.value | type == "string"))
```